# Variable input arguments in PHP

Tags: php, variables, input

I have an half PHP/half algorithmic question. I will have random inputs between 0 and 4. they will be used in the same query such as

```
  <?php  SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE inputs in (input0,input1,input2)  //for 3 inputs
          SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE inputs in (input0,input1)  //for 2 inputs
         //do nothing for zero inputs ?>
```

I believe this is the start point.

```
 <?php
 function myfunc(){
   $args = func_get_args();
  foreach ($args as $arg)
   echo $arg."/n";
 }
  myfunc('hello', 'world', '.');
      ?>
```

Now I think I can run the foreach loop n times for n individual inputs but I couldn't figure out how to use them in the query effectively. Can I create an array and pass it somehow to the query as inputs?

thanks

arda

Comment: Have you tried `implode(",",func_get_args())`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier if you passed an array to the function instead of multiple scalar arguments? Frankly, variable arguments come to mind much more frequently than it's a good idea to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also pass your function an array:

```
function myfunc(array('input2','input1'));
```

But to answer your question using `func_get_args`:

```
<?php
function buildQuery() {
    $args = func_get_args();

    $q = implode(', ',$args);

    return 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE inputs in ('.$q.');';
}

echo buildQuery('input0','input1');
?>
```

Outputs:

> SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE inputs in (input0, input1);

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to sanitize your inputs first before you use them in a query. Try this

```
$i = impode(", ", array_map(function($a) {
   return '"' . mysql_real_escape_string($a) . '"';
}, func_get_args());
```

and then replace `(input0,input1)` with content of `$i` like this

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE inputs in " . $i;
```